# Como fazer um input não aceitar o termo "Brazilian Music"

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ou seja, se tiver escrito "Brazilian Music" dentro do imput ele da um erro e não aceitar.

**Exemplo.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando tiver "Brazilian Music" ele não vai prosseguir.. TEM COMO FAZER ISSO ?

**MEU CODIGO:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Gerador de post - musicas.onlinee.top</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

<style media="screen">
  body {
    background: #daeaed;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(218,234,237,1) 0,rgba(252,248,231,1) 44%,rgba(237,247,228,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(218,234,237,1) 0,rgba(252,248,231,1) 44%,rgba(237,247,228,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(218,234,237,1) 0,rgba(252,248,231,1) 44%,rgba(237,247,228,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#daeaed',endColorstr='#edf7e4',GradientType=0);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
  }
</style>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo" style="margin-top: 3%;margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <center>
          <a href="/postador"><img src="https://musicas.onlinee.top/imagens/logotipo.png" alt="Postador - musicas.onlinee.top" style="max-width: 230px;"></a>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="formulario_gerar" style="background: #fff;border-radius: 10px;border: 1px solid #ccc;padding: 40px;">
        <form action="grava.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <label><i class="fas fa-font"></i> Titulo da postagem</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="titulo" name="titulo_post" value=""  autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label><i class="fas fa-link"></i> Capa (poster)</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="link_capa" name="link_capa" value="<?=$capa_post?>" autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Artista (cantor)</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="artista_cantor" value="<?php if(!isset($artist->contributors[0]->name)){echo "Vários artistas";}else{while($x <= $num_artist) {if(isset($artist->contributors[$cont++]->name)) {if($virgula++ > 0){echo ", ";}echo $artist->contributors[$contar_artista++]->name;}$x++;}} ?>" name="artista_cantor" autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label><i class="fas fa-folder"></i> Música/Album</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="musica_album" name="musica_album" value="<?=$json_str['title'];?>" autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label><i class="fas fa-tag"></i> Gênero</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="genero_post" name="genero" value="<?php echo $genero_novo ?>" name="genero_post" autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label><i class="fas fa-tag"></i> Ano de lançamento</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="ano_de_lancamento" value="<?php if(isset($json_str['release_date'])) { echo substr($json_str['release_date'], 0, -6); }?>" name="ano_de_lancamento" autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label><i class="fas fa-file"></i> Formato</label>
              <input class="form-control" id="formato_post" name="formato_post" value="<?php if($json_str["nb_tracks"] > 1) { echo "ZIP / MP3 / 320 Kbps";}else{ echo "MP3 / 320 Kbps";} ?>" autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <label><i class="fas fa-download"></i> Link de download</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="url_download" id="link_de_download" autocomplete="off" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <label><i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i> Lista de músicas</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" name="lista_musicas" id="lista_de_musicas" rows="5" required><?php $x = 1;while($x <= $num_tracks) {echo $title = $count_number++.'. '.$json_str['tracks']['data'][$contar++]['title'].'&#10;';$x++;} ?></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <center>
            <button type="submit" name="publicar" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-code"></i> Publicar</button>
          </center>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No input poderá ter algo a mais, como "Brazilian Music 2018" ou deve ser filtrado apenas se o conteúdo for Brazilian Music?

Comment: Ele vai aceitar varias coisas, porem não pode aceitar "Brazilian Music"

Comment: Não é mais sensato fazer uma lista do que pode ser aceito?

Comment: Não, pq e uma api que coloca.. e tem vários!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma verificação bem simples é capturar o submit do formulário e verificar a string vinda do `input`:

```js
$("form").submit(function(){
   
   var genero = $("#genero_post").val().toLowerCase().trim();
   
   if(genero == "brazilian music"){
      console.log("Ops!");
      return false;
   }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <input id="genero_post" type="text" value="Brazilian Music">
   <br>
   <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Se a string for "*brazilian music*" (sem diferenciar maiúsculas de minúsculas), o formulário não é enviado (`return false`).

Se quiser verificar se na string possui o termo "*Brazilian Music*" (também sem diferenciar maiúsculas de minúsculas), pode usar o método `.test()`:

```js
$("form").submit(function(){
   
   var genero = $("#genero_post").val().toLowerCase();
   
   if(/brazilian music/.test(genero)){
      console.log("Ops!");
      return false;
   }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <input id="genero_post" type="text" value="Brazilian Music 123">
   <br>
   <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

> Se quiser verificar vários termos, separe-os com uma barra vertical
>   `|`:
>
> ```
> /termo 1|termo 2|termo 3/.test(genero)
> ```
>
> Mas se forem muitos termos, eu sugeriria o uso de uma array.

Comment: E quando eu quiser bloquear 2 termos.. Ou seja, bloquear "Brazilian Music" + "Termo 02"

Comment: Não importa se for maiusculizo ou minusculo então neh ? dessa forma..

Comment: Tem como integrar com essa mensagem de erro: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#server-side

Assim, fica vermelho, falando que não aceita ?

Comment: OK, ficaria muito grato.

Comment: após o input do gênero, vc coloca essa div: `<div class="invalid-feedback text-hide">
Nome inválido
</div>
`

Comment: e altera o if do jquery: `if(/brazilian music|termo 2/.test(genero)){
      $("#genero_post").addClass("is-invalid").next().removeClass("text-hide");
      return false;
   }`

Comment: Vai ficar assim: https://jsfiddle.net/n62tkegs/

Comment: Ótimo, obrigado ;)

Comment: Só o detalhe que coisas /entre barras/ podem se comportar de maneira não literal. Por exemplo, o ponto vai encaixar com qualquer coisa. Isso acontece porque é uma expressão regular. O uso demonstrado pelo dvd foi perfeito para o seu caso, mas é bom lembrar que não é a bala de prata **sempre**.